# Spring Boot JPA 2 - Oracle DB - Table name starting with a digit

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I have a table defined in an Oracle DB starting with a digit, i.e. **"01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION"**.
I have no problems accessing the data in the table using a GUI with an universal DB client, like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).
DBeaver suggests using double quotes around the table name, like in the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION" WHERE ...
```

This works very well and I can access the data without any problems.

I'm working on a Java application for collecting the same data, using Spring Boot 2 and Spring Data JPA.

Simply annotating the entity with:

```
@Entity(name = "01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION")
```

and/or:

```
@Table(name = "01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION")
```

unfortunately produces an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at it.ecubit.dgsaf.data.config.ApplicationConfig.main(ApplicationConfig.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 01 near line 1, column 29 [select generatedAlias0 from 01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION as generatedAlias0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 01 near line 1, column 29 [select generatedAlias0 from 01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION as generatedAlias0]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at it.ecubit.dgsaf.data.config.ApplicationConfig.lambda$0(ApplicationConfig.java:32) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:767) [spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 01 near line 1, column 29 [select generatedAlias0 from 01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION as generatedAlias0]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:743) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:797) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:760) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:784) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:761) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:399) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:84) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:638) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 01 near line 1, column 29 [select generatedAlias0 from 01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION as generatedAlias0]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:622) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:734) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

The key here is the message "unexpected token: 01 near line 1, column 29 [select generatedAlias0 from 01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION as generatedAlias0]".

I've tried several workarounds to make it work, including:

- using backticks in table name (inside the annotation)
- using double quotes in table name ("\"01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION\"")
- even using a custom naming strategy, using the class shown below (and defining it as the desired physical naming strategy inside application.yml, using the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy`)

  ```
   public class QuotedUpperCaseNamingStrategy extends CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy {    

     @Override
     public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
       if( identifier == null || identifier.getText() == null ) {
           return null;
       }
       String tableName = identifier.getText();
       Identifier result = new DoubleQuotedIdentifier(Identifier.quote(Identifier.toIdentifier(tableName.toUpperCase())));
       log.info("QuotedUpperCaseNamingStrategy (table name) : " + tableName + " -> " + result.toString());
       return result;
     }

     @Override
     public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
       if( identifier == null || identifier.getText() == null ) {
           return null;
       }
       String catalogName = identifier.getText();
       Identifier result = new DoubleQuotedIdentifier(Identifier.quote(Identifier.toIdentifier(catalogName.toUpperCase())));
       log.info("QuotedUpperCaseNamingStrategy (catalog name) : " + catalogName + " -> " + result.toString());
       return result;
     }

     @Override
     protected boolean isCaseInsensitive(JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
       return false;
     }
   }
  ```

Nothing works... Any hints on how to solve this problem?

I'm using:

- Spring Boot 2.6.0 with Spring Data JPA
- [Oracle UCP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/intro.htm) and Oracle ojdbc8 driver
- Java JDK 1.8 (Oracle)

on a Linux workstation.

Comment: In general, quoted object names should be avoided. Once you use quotes to define an object name - say to make it case sensitive or start with a number - you must thereafter *always* use quotes to refer to that object. As you are discovering, this can be difficult or even impossible in some contexts. While others might have a technical hack for this, the best advice I have is to avoid the issue entirely by sticking to valid Oracle naming formats in the first place. There's no guarantee that custom formats will work with different clients or programming languages.

Comment: '.hinernate' in your property is wrong. Hopefully it is a cut and paste issue, but if not, you might want to recheck your results using spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy and spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy with different options, but looks like the SQL table name is already "01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION" where you get the error, so it might not be being modified - it just doesn't like it not starting with a numeric character.

Comment: This seems a Hibernate issue, not JPA, as JPA mandates this should work - what is the error when you use @Table(name = "\"01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION\"") as your docs suggested?  If that doesn't work, check the hibernate docs or an alternate JPA provider to see if there is a way to avoid it going through the QueryTranslatorImpl.parse on the SQL.

Comment: If you cannot get it to work through JPA (there should be a way) then a last resort could be to create an alias in Oracle to a non-quoted identifier (such as `FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION_01`).

Comment: Check this property: `globally_quoted_identifiers`

Comment: Thanks @Chris, property `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` corrected (it was only a typo).

Comment: @Chris, using:
`@Table(name = "\"01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION\"")` 
without customizing the naming strategy causes this error:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [``01_fhir_medicinal_product_definition``]` (1 backtick)
Using the custom naming strategy shown in the question, I have this error:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [select generatedAlias0 from "01_FHIR_MEDICINAL_PRODUCT_DEFINITION" as generatedAlias0]`
and this is really strange, cause it was my best guess to make it work...